# Help solving vector difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, matrix-equations

Hi I need help solving the following difference equation:

$ X_{t} b_{t-1} = X_{t-1} b_{t-2} - C_{t-1}$

where X and C are vectors and b is a scalar. Is there a way I can solve this for X?

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
Y_t = X_t b_{t-1}
$$

we have

$$
Y_t-Y_{t-1} = C_{t-1}
$$

with solution

$$
Y_t = c_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{t-1}C_k = X_t b_{t-1}
$$